# Laravel 4 use multiple layouts (and domains) with 1 install

Tags: php, templates, laravel, laravel-4

I want to have multiple sites at 1 laravel install. The sites have the same functionallity and only few minor layout changes and text changes.

I placed this in my routes.php

```
$requestingSite = Request::server('SERVER_NAME');;

switch($requestingSite)
{
    case 'domain.com':
    define('SITE_ID', 1);
    break;
}
```

But what's the best way to use different layouts for each site? When I try for example to use SITE_ID in a blade.php file it gives an error.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using constant you can use `View::share('SITE_ID', 1)`, this is accessible from all your views via `{{ $SITE_ID }}`.

Comment: Thank you, but how should I include different files for each site? Was thinking for something like @include('layouts'.{{$SITE_ID}}.'page') but that gives errors because it makes php code in already php

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But how should I use this in combination with protected $layout = 'template'; $this->layout->content = View::make("layouts.{$SITE_ID}.content"); in the controller?